# Get into the database Wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I can not get into the database of my site. My hosting provider does not support database management. Enter the link domen.com/phpmyadmin but gives error 404. I found wp-config.php in which the registered username and password to the database.
How do I get into the database of my site? I need to make a backup.
In folder 'config' I have only 'defines.inc.php'

---

On the same server I have a website on prestashop in the database that I can go through phpmyadmin.

Comment: Contact your hosting provider and ask them for details on how to connect to Mysql. Even if your provider does not run phpmyadmin you can use software such Sequel Pro or Mysql Workbench to connect to the DB.

Comment: If you have the ip/address, username and password of the DB.Try to connect using a DBMS like MySQL workbench. Or try to find an alternative through Cpanel. If nothing works for you, contact your host to setup a phpmyadmin for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to access remotely if it was configured this way, if you need a graphical interface you can use [Mysql Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) . If you can't access remotely and can upload php script try uploading [adminer](http://www.adminer.org/)  or installing phpMyAdmin yourself.